# Search: Operations error ldap

Tags: php, ldap

Доброго времени суток! нужно получить всех пользователей из AD, есть такой скрипт:

```
        $ldap_host = 'ns.domain.ru';
    $ldap_port = '389';
    $base_dn = 'DC=ns,DC=domain,DC=ru';
    $filter='(Type=*)';

    $param = array('Type','Description','Office','Business Phone');

    $connect = ldap_connect($ldap_host,$ldap_port);
    if(!$connect)
        die('cannot connect');

    ldap_set_option($connect,LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);
    ldap_set_option($connect,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);

    $bind = ldap_bind($connect);
    if(!$bind) 
        die('cannot bind');

    $read = ldap_search($connect,$base_dn,$filter,$param);
```

выдает ошибку Search: Operations error. в чем может быть проблема?    
PS: в error log такая запись: client denied by server configuration: X:/denwer/www/denwer/errors/403.php